# My code won't render the PHP from a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I've been working with this one page forever using MAMP and I can't get the PHP to render. It must be something with getting the info from the table but I can't figure out what. I'm pretty sure I have everything lined up correctly.

For a while it was just sending me back jibberish and then nothing but eventually I got it render the HTML through localhost by switching the while loop to a `do-while` loop so that it would run through once. So the issue must be with the connection to MySQL I'm thinking, but I don't know what.

```
<?php 

$product_id = $_GET['id'];
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'legend');
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=" . $product_id . "'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Name: <?php echo $row['unitOne']; ?></p>
        <p>Box Quantity: <?php echo $row['unitTwo']; ?></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: first of all check your connection with this: `$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'legend') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); `

Comment: youre missing a `'` should be: `mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='" . $product_id . "'");`. Also you should use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Do NOT put your html, head and body declarations into a while loop. That will just generate very invalid HTML. The content that you want to generate, according to your code, should be within your BODY tags.

Comment: nothing to do with phpmyadmin, its not a database

Comment: Just as little note: _phpMyAdmin_ is just a tool to show the content of a mysql database. So your problem is not related to _phpMyAdmin_ at all. It is just _php_ and _mysql_ in that case that is related to your problem.

Comment: Following the comment from @prodigitalson, this code has a SQL injection vulnerability. If you put it live, it might get hacked.

Comment: *Check for errors!* If we got a cent every time someone did not check for errors we'd all be rich.

Answer (score 0):

Try to structure your code this way and please consider all the comments below your first post. I also recommend reading this article that will clarify what prepared statements and bound parameters are: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Remember to always construct your HTML markup correctly. There should never be more than one open and close tag for *html*, *head* and *body*. And if you do have more that can surely mess things up for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = ?"; //for security we will be using prepared statements
$stmt = $link -> mysqli -> prepare($query); //$link contains your database connection
$stmt -> bind_param('i', $id); //$id contains a product id the "i" will define it as an integer
$stmt -> execute();

$result = $stmt -> fetch_result();
while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){ //loop out the results
    echo '<div>';
        echo '<p>Name: '.$row['unitOne'].'</p>';
        echo '<p>Box Quantity: '.$row['unitTwo'].'</p>';
     echo '</div>';
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```